# Giving a user SFTP access only with access to subdirectory outside of home?

Tags: ssh, centos, terminal, sftp

I have user [USER A] account which contains scripts and a `downloads` folder.
I would like to create a new account [USER B] so that the user has read/write (SFTP and not full SSH) access to their home folder, but also their home folder should contain a symlink to the `downloads` folder from USER A.
Preferably I would like to give read-only access to the downloads folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble? Do you know how to create a new user? Do you know how to create symlink? Is it the read-only access that is the issue?